Aws: Authorizer name must be unique
In my template.yaml I have this config for an authorizer and API, when I try to deploy it I get this error:

Authorizer name must be unique.Authorizer CognitoAuthorizer already exists in this RestApi

CognitoAuthorizer:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Authorizer
    Properties:
      Name: CognitoAuthorizer
      RestApiId: !Ref UserApi
      Type: COGNITO_USER_POOLS
      IdentitySource: method.request.header.Authorization
      ProviderARNs:
        - !GetAtt UserPool.Arn  

UserApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      Name: UserApi
      StageName: Prod
      Auth:
        DefaultAuthorizer: CognitoAuthorizer
        Authorizers:
          CognitoAuthorizer:
            UserPoolArn: !GetAtt UserPool.Arn

I'm trying to do a relation between my API and Authorizer
